# How to make a pendulum move with a given, changing, velocity

Tags: vb.net

I am currently stuck trying to figure out how I will make my pendulum move with its changing velocity, due to gravity. I attempted to do this:

---

```
Do Until StopProgram = True
        Do Until Count = v
            Application.DoEvents()

            If DirectionNegative = False Then
                Me.Refresh()
                Count += 1
                Angle += 1
                RadianAngle = Angle * PlaceHolder
                If Angle >= 51 Then
                    Angle = 49
                    DirectionNegative = True
                End If
            ElseIf DirectionNegative = True Then
                Me.Refresh()
                Count += 1
                Angle -= 1
                RadianAngle = Angle * PlaceHolder
                If Angle <= -51 Then
                    Angle = -49
                    DirectionNegative = False
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        Count = 0

    Loop
```

---

This makes the pendulum move with the v (Final velocity (Using SUVAT)) but currently this is working by making it run for however long v is, I would like the pendulum to swing X amount per second, where X changes depending on v. I have been told I should try this with multithreading but after researching this I am confused on the whole thing and I do not know where to begin with any of this, bar what I have.

Comment: You have to start with model of pendulum, including its length - then you can write down required formulas etc. Multithreading is not related in any way :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum

Comment: I do have a pendulum currently, I can change the length of its string and the planet it is on, changing the gravity. It currently swings at a constant rate, which is my issue. I was told I should use multithreading for this due to the calculations it will constantly be making.

Comment: And it should swing at constant rate, assuming its length and planet doesn't change.

Comment: Its velocity should change due to the gravity slowing it down or speeding it up. (The v in the animation in the link you sent me)

Comment: I would start with timer and harmonic oscillator formula (angle dependency of time). I would then calculate angle (from time); velocity would be result of this process (could be calculated as location derivative). I can't exactly understand your requirements - but you must understand physics of pendulum before coding its motion.

Comment: I have a way of working out the velocity I need with the equation "v = (s + (1 / 2) * a * (t * t)) / t", where t is the length of time from the program start (I know this should be changed to something like, time since start of swing towards the pendulum's rest point), s is the Length of the string and a is the gravity

Comment: I would use (from wikipedia article): angle(t) = starting_angle * cos(2 * pi * t / period)

Comment: I am not sure what this equation would give me, is it the angle at a certain time? And where does gravity factor in?

Comment: Gravity (+ length) allows you to calculate period.

Comment: Yeah, using T = 2pi root(l/g) but I will need the time since that particular swing started for use in suvat

Comment: Save it (time) then and count from saved one, whatsa problem? On related note, I had to look up, what SUVAT means - looks like simple equations between some physical parameters, not directly usable with pendulum. I'm not english and my physics courses were too long ago. Anyway, SO thinks that we have been too verbose here; I have nothing more to say.